# Convert String to byte array (0x) - Java

Tags: java, apache, hex, arrays, apache-commons-codec

I have a String value as "0x0601930600058000050001", need to convert to byte array

```
byte[] codes1 = new byte[]{(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x93,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x05,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x05,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01};

    for(byte b : codes1){
        System.out.println(b);
    }
System.out.println("======================");

byte[] cod = "0x0601930600058000050001".getBytes();
for(byte b : cod){
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Both the results are different, how to make them same. 1st loop output is the actual one what i am expecting, 2nd loop is wrong output.

If you see, i am splitting each 2 bytes and type casting and using 0x to get the actual value.

Question : Is there any predefined method (Apache commons codec) which can help me to do the same task as 1st loop ? I get that String value dynamically at run time.

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your string is a hexadecimal representation of a byte array!

With guava you can do this:

```
byte[] bytes = BaseEncoding.base16().decode(mystring)
```

Comment: it's not accepting alphanumeric ? for ex : 06038f040003800406

Comment: If you expect lowercase letters, than you need to tell this the encoder: BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().decode("06038f040003800406");

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
byte[] result = myString.getBytes();
```

or

```
byte[] result = myString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This is not getting the actual expected result :                                  byte[] cod = "0x0601930600058000050001".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));                                                                                                         for(byte b : cod){
  System.out.println(b);
}